# Authentication in .htaccess in subdomain affects the main domain site

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7

I have a very strange problem with password protection in a subdomain. I use a subdomain `test.example.com`, and in order to avoid duplicate content issues, and to keep the test site private, I have added these lines on top in .htaccess for this test site to prompt users:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home/httpd/mydomain/test.example.com/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

This authentication solution has worked for years, but now suddenly when accessing the **main domain** `example.com`, the user is prompted with a dialog that demands authentication. The message is that `test.example.com` demands authentication. So the password protection in the test site affects the main domain site.

To grant access for all users to the main site again, I have commented out the relevant lines in .htaccess for the test site.

To be clear I should also mention that I am not talking about a redirection to the test site. When accessing the main site, this is also where the user ends up. But the password prompt still refers to the test site.

On the server no changes has been made to the vhosts in a long time.

So how can the password protection in the .htaccess file in the test site affect the main domain site? Seems impossible to me. But yet this is what happens.

The site is built with Drupal 7 and is updated to the latest version. The only change in recent time is a Drupal update (7.82).

Comment: You probably have an external asset _from_ `test.mysite.com` embedded in `mysite.com` somewhere ...

Comment: What is your file structure? Where does the subdomain resolve to in relation to the main domain?

Comment: MrWhite: The respective folders are positioned "side by side" in the top level (/home/httpd/mydomain/test.mysite.se/.htaccess etc, /home/httpd/mydomain/www.mysite.se/.htacess etc )

Comment: CBroe: The only thing I can think of is a React app that resides on the top level (above the respective docroots): /home/httpd/mydomain/react_app/). That app is called by both sites. There is also a rewrite rule in .htaccess in both sites to access that folder. This has not caused any problems for at least 2 years though.

Comment: Have you used browser dev tools, to see if you can spot any requests going to `test.mysite.com`?

Comment: CBroe: I just checked and there is actually one (1) image on the home page that is fetched from the test site... I will sort that out at once. I cross my fingers and hope that the problem will go away after that. The more I think about it, this is probably the cause. Thanks for the tip!